# ¿Como poner el icono con esquinas redondeadas en una App de Android hecha en IONIC?

Tags: android, ionic

Tengo 2 aplicaciones desarrolladas con IONIC (v3 y v4) ya agregue los resources en el formato especificado y sin transparencias, en la ficha de la aplicación en Play Console subi el icono cuadrado y me hace una previsualización con esquinas redondeadas (solo aparece así en la Play Store), pero cuando instalo la App en mi equipo o equipos aparece cuadrado, alguien sabe como puedo solucionar ese pequeño detalle, de antemano gracias.

Intente poner el icono con esquinas redondeadas en los resources pero al subir la App no me la acepta, según lei se hace en automático, al menos en la App Store de Apple no tengo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Los iconos de la PlayStore deben seguir unas guidelines y si tu icono no las cumple se le fuerza a cumplirlas.
Te dejo dos referencias:

[Especificaciones de diseño](https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications)

[Iconos adaptativos](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más específico y aclarar la solución al problema?

Comment: Gracias Daniel, los iconos que tengo en la app cumplen con lo que pide tanto Google como Apple, el tema es que al instalar la app no realiza el redondeo, no se si se necesite alguna configuración adicional dentro de la app o la play store.